# Trying to join a .dat file with a .asc file using Python or Excel

Tags: python, excel, parsing, merge, uniqueidentifier

guys.

I've got a bit of a unique issue trying to merge two big data files together. Both files have a column of the same data (patent number) with all other columns different.

The idea is to join them such that these patent number columns align so the other data is readable and connected.

Just the first few lines of the **.dat** file looks like:

```
IL      1   Chicago 10030271    0   3930271
PA      1   Bedford 10156902    0   3930272
MO      1   St. Louis   10112031    0   3930273
IL      1   Chicago 10030276    0   3930276
```

And the **.asc**:

```
02 US corporation   No change   11151713    TRANSCO PROD INC    58419
02 US corporation   No change   11151720    SECURE TELECOM INC  502530 
02 US corporation   No change   11151725    SOA SYSTEMS INC 520365 
02 US corporation   No change   11151738    REVTEK INC  473150
```

The .dat file is too large to open fully in Excel so I don't think reorganizing it there is an option (rather I don't know if it is or not through any macros I've found online yet).

Quite a newbie question I feel but does anyone know how I could link these data sets together (preferably using Python) with this patent number unique identifier?

Answer (score 2):

You will want to write a program that reads in the data from the two files you would like to merge. You will open the file and parse the data for each line. From there you are able to write the data to a new file in any order that you would like. This is accomplish-able through python file IO.

pseudo code:

```
def filehandler(self, filename1, filename2):
     Fd =open(filename1, "r")
     Fd2 = open(filename2, "r")
     while True:
         line1 = Fd.readline()
         if not line1: break # this will exit the loop if there is no more to read
         Line1_array = line1.split()
         # first line of first file is split and saved in an array deliniated by spaces.
```

Comment: Fair enough but will this work if both data sets are not equal in length? I believe one has many more entries than exists in the other so I need to use the unique identifier to match them.

Comment: Sure can. Add an If statement in their to check and see if there is another line. This will be the same way you break out of the while loop.